# Pass all the elements of dictionary together to a function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which takes dataframes and unions all of the input dataframe.

Currently I have all the dataframe stored in a dictionary. for ex:

my_dict = { 'df_1': 'first DataFrame Object', 'df_2': 'second DataFrame object'}

How do I pass all the elements  of dictionary together dynamically to below function? I need to pass like

```
unionAll(my_dict['df_1'],my_dict['df_2']) # how to generate this dnamically, given number of elements in dictionary would change in each run
```

```
#Function Definition:

def unionAll(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

Comment: If you don't need the dict keys, you can try my_dict.values(). I'm not sure this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to access per key, just access the [values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) directly. Since you are accepting it as a variable amount of arguments `*dfs`, then you have to unwrap it first via `*values` before passing.

```
unionAll(*my_dict.values())
```

Comment: can you help me understand why do we need to add * during function call as well? for ex: below code works even if I does not pass * during invoke.However in above case it does not work, if dont prefix * while passing dictionary. my_dict = {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}

def fun(*args):
    print("TYPE=", type(args))

fun(my_dict.values()) # <<it works>>
fun(*my_dict.values()) # works

Comment: This `def unionAll(*dfs)` is equivalent to `def unionAll(df1, df2, df3,... dfn)`. So, if you want to pass a sequence `seq = [df1, df2, df3,... dfn]`, then you can't just pass that whole sequence `unionAll(seq)` because it would be like `def unionAll(df1=[df1, df2, df3,... dfn], df2, df3,... dfn)` when what you want is `def unionAll(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3,... dfn=dfn)`. Thus, you need to unwrap the sequence first before passing `unionAll(*dfs)`. See [this](https://paiza.io/projects/e/No-MleSJivupjuEqh6JeYg?theme=twilight).

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in the last part of my comment, I didn't mean `*dfs`, it should be `*seq`, so the call should be  `unionAll(*seq)`.